# UiPath - Search role in web table and select it if exist

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I’m working in a process to **delete roles for several users** (500).
I did a process, but I’m seeing it isn’t working well. Only select the checkbox Role, if it is in the beginning.

I’ve created a DataTable, This DataTable contains base information with `user_id`, my key field to find this particular role and delete it.
In this process, I need to access each user to browse his roles. All roles change according to the user.

My problem is how can I browse the (web table) roles, find and select the correct role, through its checkbox.

Here an image with three cases that could be appears:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but your example is not well explained. I have no idea what you mean with first and second row. Please give 2 examples of a user that has a role and one who has not. Please give input and your wanted output. Thanks.

Comment: You need a For Each activity based on the user id, and within the loop, access the web table for the user.  Read the table into a datatable and filter it for the role you want.  If it's found then it's in the web table for the user, locate the text on the web page and set the associated checkbox.  Please post your workflow as it'll make things easier to explain if we have a point of reference